# How do I find which part in my program is using pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

I did a cpu profiling on my C++ multithreaded program using perf and flamegraph and seeing pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal in the flamegraph are taking some CPU. But strange thing is in the program I didn't use them explicitly at all. So wonder if there is some way to find if any of the lib I use is using them? And in one place I am using C++ std::mutex and std::lock_guard, so do the C++ mutex and lock_gurad use the pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal internally in C++? The other lib I use is the boost asio, I use its strand to make sure of the thread safety. Wonder if in boost asio strand it use them internally?

Or if there is any way I can find if any of other libs I use would use them? In the flamegraph stack before the pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal are [unknown] so not sure what is calling them. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly how a C++ Standard Library implementation implements threading support is up to the implementors. It wouldn't surprise me to see them built atop pthread.

Comment: `pthread_cond_wait` and `pthread_cond_signal` is used for `condition variable`, so not used in `std::mutex` or `std::lock_guard`. I think it's used in `boost asio` which is providing the asynchronous operation. So, I believe that, you should check the place which are using boost asio API